# Not able to compute value of negative base in JAVA

Tags: java, android, math, computation

In my Android app I am trying to evaluate the expression: (-2^(x)) but can't seem 
to get the Math.pow() method from the JAVA library to work. I am able to evaluate (2^(x)) but not the other with negative base. 
Here is a look at the Logs. The y values are all returned as NaN. 
[image]

to evaluate I am using the following statements:

```
double result = Math.pow(x,exponent);
result = coefficient * result;
```

I don't know what might seem to be the problem. Perhaps is the way the negative base is set up.

thanks for any advice
    return multiplier * Math.pow(base,result);

Comment: Post error log instead of image

Comment: `Math.pow` [seems fine to me](http://rextester.com/DWIDQ24445) with a negative base.  Can you give us a reproducible example?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what do you mean by a reproducible example?

Comment: If it is not working out for you, simply do (2^x) and in the end, multiply the result with (-1). Unless you are talking about (-2)^x. Even if that is the case, just check x is even or odd and multiple with (-1) accordingly

Comment: I think Math.pow works with -ve values. Error is not there in -ve values.

Comment: @Kaushal28 the app does not crash. no error is produced. The graph of (-2^(x)) is simply not created. All the y values are returned as NaN

Comment: Can you share your code and state your expected result?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are trying to compute (-2) to the power `x`, where `x` is one of the `x` values shown in the image: this does not work unless `x` is an integer.  The reason is that the answer is not a real number.  (For example, what is (-1)^0.5?  That's the square root of -1, which is `i`, an imaginary number, not a real number.)  The `x` values shown in the image are all non-integers (there appear to be some that are very close to integers but still aren't--there's a non-zero in the last decimal place).  Thus, the results all come out as `NaN`.

This is explicit in the javadoc for `Math.pow`:

> If the first argument is finite and less than zero:
>
> if the second
> argument is a finite even integer, the result is equal to the result
> of raising the absolute value of the first argument to the power of
> the second argument
>
> if the second argument is a finite odd integer,
> the result is equal to the negative of the result of raising the
> absolute value of the first argument to the power of the second
> argument
>
> if the second argument is finite and not an integer, then the
> result is NaN.

If what you're doing is something other than (-2)^x, then your question is confusing and needs clarification.

Comment: am doing this: -1 * 2^x  , a human will recognize this, but Math.pow() does not. As you said, non-integer exponents will return NaN due to roots with even indices. I will just have to rewrite the expression or force the code to recognize integer values of x and evaluate those instead of the other ones. @ajb

Comment: This has to be it, though the OP did not explain things well +1.

Comment: I'm suspicious of the way you're handling `x`.  You have a lot of values that look like `-12.900000000000003`.  This suggests that you're trying to step `x` up by 0.1, but doing it in a way that results in roundoff errors, so that when `x` is supposed to be an integer, it still isn't.  That can happen when you use `double`, because the value 0.1 _cannot_ be represented exactly as a `double`.  My suggestion: use an integer that is incremented by 1 each time, and divide that by 10, instead of using 0.1 as an increment.  That way, when `x` is an integer, it will be exact.

Comment: yes am stepping x up by 0.05 or 0.1, I will try your tip, but it will be hard to change more than 10,000 lines of android code. Guess, for next time. @ajb

Answer (score 1):

A negative base with a fractional exponent is a complex number with a real and imaginary part.  The Math.pow function is not equipped to return a complex number; a double return value can't represent or refer to a complex value.

The problem happens because of the way all languages represent floating point numbers.  You can no more represent 0.1 exactly as a binary number than you can 1/3 using base 10.